# Missing rows when inserting DataTable to MySQL database table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the following code to insert Data tables to MySQL

```
public void BulkInsert(DataTable userDataTable , string DestinationTableName, string DestinationDatabaseName, MySqlConnection ConnectionString)
{

    try {

        ConnectionString.Open();
        ConnectionString.ChangeDatabase(DestinationDatabaseName);

        using (MySqlTransaction tran = ConnectionString.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = ConnectionString;
                cmd.Transaction = tran;
                cmd.CommandText = $"select * from `" + DestinationTableName + "` ORDER By Time DESC LIMIT 0;";

                using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;
                    using (MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
                    {
                        cb.SetAllValues = true;
                        adapter.Update(userDataTable);
                        tran.Commit();
                    }
                };
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
```

The Data table has 270 Rows but only 78 are transferred to the MySQL Table ,

The data table from the user contains rows from multiple CSV files,
it seems that although the Data table has 270 rows only the rows
of the first file are being transferred and the others are ignored.

No error detected by catch.

Using MySQL 5.7 and .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2

What could be the problem ?!

Comment: Total rows loaded from CSV is less relevant than the number of rows which appear changed to the Provider.  Also, your title says INSERT but the code uses UPDATE

Comment: The DataTable starts as Blank , all rows are new. .Update() is a method, the description says it uses insert, delete and update

Comment: You should see if the DB provider agrees with you with `GetChanges()`

Comment: You are correct , the dt.GetChanges() matches the rows were inserted to the database table. I got a problem in loading the rows from the CSV files to the userDataTable , THANKS !!

Comment: We cant see how they are loaded, but I'd guess there is some minor tweak to some of them to set the RowChange flag.  There is a way to load them with all the rows set as new so they are all eligible for INSERT

Comment: The code I wrote didn't take this type of flag under consideration, I was planning to re-write the whole thing to be more efficient anyway, now I don't have an excuse to delay the task anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adapter.Insert(userDataTable) instead of adapter.Update(userDataTable)?

Think to change you code to something like this: [Alternative code to insert MySql Data](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9582c9/insert-update-delete-display-data-in-mysql-using-C-Sharp/)